# Iframe abnormaly displayed on Chrome (normal on Firefox)

Tags: css, cross-browser

On [my page](http://goo.gl/vSLlP6), the top center embedded YouTube video (iframe) fills the entire responsive container on Firefox, but for some reason it is displayed much smaller and only in the upper half of the container on Chrome:

[image]

HTML:

```
<div class='product_frame_wrap'>
    <div class='product_frame'>
        <div class='product_frame_image_vid'>
            <iframe>...</iframe>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.product_frame_wrap {
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 600px;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}
.product_frame {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) url("images/frame.png") no-repeat scroll 50% 50% / contain ;
    padding-bottom: 75%;
    position: relative;
}
.product_frame_image_vid {
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    padding-top: 5%;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
}
.product_frame_image_vid iframe {
    height: 100% !important;
    width: 100% !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look up browser specific css you can find hacks. The below code will only effect chrome browsers. When you set the iframe's height to 200% it seems to fill in correctly in chrome.

**Adding the below snippet to your css should fix the problem:**

```
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) { 
    .product_frame_image_vid iframe { height:200%; } 
}
```

Comment: Wow, terrific! A media query for Chrome :)